# Mission control move a space shortcut not working in Monterey

Tags: mission-control, monterey

After I updated to MacOS Monterey, move right/left a space keyboard shortcut (mission control) is no longer working. I even changed the key mapping but this doesn't seem to fix it. And interestingly, when I hit the shortcut key, I hear an alert sound.

I use this command everyday, any comment would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you use an extended keyboard? If so the numbers above qwerty & those on the 10-key pad are considered different.

Comment: No, I use the regular version of apple magic keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had shortcuts to define file labels defined as Services, but somehow the definition wasn't properly migrated when upgrading to macOS 11. At the end I had to review all keyboard shortcuts in System Settings, remove any conflicting ones and reboot twice to get rid of the stale definitions.

Comment: Please don't roll back useful edits. They are done following the guidelines of the site and standard English language rules.

Comment: This reads more like a story than an actual answer. Can you edit your post down to the actual part which answers the question by explaining how you solved the problem (would assume one or two paragraphs)? Don‘t worry too much about getting the wording or spelling right, other users can support on this with an edit on their own.

Comment: Not sure why you rollback any edits to your answer. Please have look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing to understand the purpose of edits. If there is a specific reason against any edit, please leave a comment.

Comment: Please raise a question on Meta if you want to discuss the lock on this answer.